# Help proving an equality about arithmetic functions

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, arithmetic-functions

So I have this equality to prove for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$:

$$ \sum_{d|n} \sigma(d) \phi(\frac{n}{d}) = n \tau(n) $$

So I was able to show that left and right side are multiplicative.

So how can I prove that the left side is equal to the right.

So if  it holds for $n=1$, $n=2$

Then I take:

$n=p_1^{\alpha_1}...p_k^{\alpha_k}$
And have to see if it works for this.

But am not sure how do I represent the left side, since I don't know how 
 this actually affects the sum $\phi(\frac{n}{d})$.

Any help, answers or hints would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_function#Convolution

Comment: Since both sides are multiplicative, you just need to check it for prime powers.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee does this mean it's only a product of two multiplicative functions?

Comment: @DanielFischer So only set $n=p^k$ and then check it ?  we only solved in class such examples where we used always this: $n=p_1^{\alpha_1}...p_k^{\alpha_k}$  is it the same, or what is the principle behind using only $n=p^k$. I apologize for the long reply, but just making sure i can use this.

Comment: If $f$ is a multiplicative function and $n = p_1^{\alpha_1}\cdot \dotsc \cdot p_k^{\alpha_k}$, then $$f(n) = \prod_{\kappa = 1}^k f(p_{\kappa}^{\alpha_{\kappa}})\,.$$ Thus if $f$ and $g$ are two multiplicative functions, then $f(p^{\alpha}) = g(p^{\alpha})$ for all primes $p$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb{N}$ already implies $f(n) = g(n)$ for all $n$. Typically, it's much easier to check the equality at prime powers than at general $n$, so that saves some work.